# how to share audio on whatsapp.. its not working

Tags: java, android

How to share audio on WhatsApp? This is my code:

```
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
 shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(dialog_audio));
 context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "mp3 shared!"));`
```

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? What are your actual symptoms? What is the value of `dialog_audio`?

Comment: String dialog_audio = detailDatalist_model.getPost_audio(); position of audio url.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line

```
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

and Remember to have the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: its not working..error-"sharing failed, please try again"